# MS Access 2007: Creating a "Select All" option for Append Queries

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

I have two related tables, "Distributions" and "DistributionCities", both with primary keys, designed this way so there can be multiple cities per DistributionID.

My question is, it's not uncommon for certain DistributionID's to cover *every* city.  Is there a way to automate this so that users don't have to select each in my city child subform individually? I imagine a user clicking a "Select all cities" option in lieu of the subform, at which point a new DistributionCityID is created for each city with that particular DistributionID.  I hope that makes sense.  Caveat that I'm still an amateur with Access.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using a list box or a combo box? How familiar are you with VBA (cause you need VBA and you should at least have some basic understanding)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sure you can if you have a distinct Cities table. And this can be done in SQL queries.

Comment: I've been using some VBA, I just wasn't sure how to approach this one.  I'm using a subform in datasheet view since the form is appending to two separate related tables, was the best way I found to be able to select multiple cities.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Any suggestions regarding the VBA required for this would be greatly appreciated, I'm stuck.  I'm unsure how to structure it so that it uses the master form ID field (which is an autonumber not represented on the form itself) along with each CityID.